# Column doesn't populate with lazy loading turned off

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, lazy-loading, lazy-evaluation

I have a linq query:

```
var query = from ct in ClaimTypes
            join c in Claims.OrderBy(x => x.ClaimValue)
                            .Include("SubClaims") on ct.ClaimTypeId equals c.ClaimTypeId into t
            select new { ct.ClaimTypeName, t };
```

The results were a dictionary of claims with the key being a claim type and the value being a list of claims under that claim type. Within claims, there is a column called subclaims. However, we turned off lazy loading due to server issues and now the subclaims column does not populate. Using an INCLUDE within a JOIN does not populate the column. Can anyone suggest any other solutions?

Comment: Can you join on SubClaims from the repository/dbml/whatever?

Comment: try put the include before the orderby

Comment: Ive tried putting the include before the orderby same results. Column still doesnt populate.

Comment: With no join, this query works:    
var query = from c in Claims.Include("Subclaims").OrderBy(x => x.ClaimValue)
select c;

Comment: I also know that INCLUDE does not work with a join unless you add ObjectQuery<Claim>, however, I cant cast "t" it give me an error

Answer (score 1):

You're not returning t.SubClaims in your result set. The include is applying to the sub query, not the final select. Run SQL profiler to confirm that the final select set does not include the SubClaims fields.

Try:

```
select new { ct.ClaimTypeName, t, t.SubClaims };
```

Or:

```
var query = /* you're query */;
query = query.Include(a => a.t.SubClaims);
```

Comment: That give me this error: Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type

Comment: a => a.t.SubClaims is the correct syntax however, after the "t", there are no fields as an option in intellisense.